# How to check duplicate record in access

Tags: ms-access

```
Name    Place
Ram     Delhi
Rajesh  Chennai
Ram     Bangaluru
Hitesh  Chandigarh
Ram     Orisa
```

How to check duplicate records in access.

as ram is appearing 3 times in different places in this table

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't exactly duplicates since Place is different for all of them, but if you want to find just the names that appear more than once you can do:

```
SELECT name,COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d49fc/2)</kbd>

this fiddle is in sql-server, but in access it should behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the built in Find Duplicates Query Wizard if you don't want to write your own SQL.  In Access 2010, its under the "Create" tab, then "Query Wizard", then "Find Duplicates Query".  Then select the table you want to analyze, and chose the fields to look for duplicates in ("Name" in your case).